# Input to precision_recall_curve - predict or predict_proba output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using Gaussian Naive Bayes to train a model from a Pandas data frame, but I'm getting an error when using precision_recall_curve.  The documentation says precision_recall_curve takes the predicted probabilities as input (at least as I read it) so I would expect the below to work (xtrain and xtest are Pandas data frames with 736 and 184 rows respectively; ytrain/ytest are Series with 736 and 184 rows respectively):

```
nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
predicted = nb.predict_proba(xtest)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(ytest, predicted)
```

I expect the above to work, however I receive an "IndexError: index 230 is out of bounds for size 184".  If I instead do:

```
predicted = nb.predict(xtest)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(ytest, predicted)
```

Then it executes properly.  184 is the number of rows in xtest and ytest, but 230 is not a dimension for any of those structures.  Can someone explain the difference or how I'm supposed to be using precision_recall_curve for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know where the 230 comes from, but you should really not use scikit-learn estimators on Pandas datastructures. scikit-learn expects NumPy conventions, and Pandas violates some of those (e.g. by turning 1-d arrays into column vectors instead of row vectors). Also, is this a binary classification task?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following if this is a binary classification,

```
predicted = nb.predict_proba(xtest)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(ytest, predicted[:,1])
```